# Windows Azure Ping Site

Tags: azure

I am running a site using Windows Azure Cloud. Is there a way I can ping my site every 20 minutes? My site has low traffic and I need to stop the site from starting and stopping the app pool all the time.

Comment: Can we confirm this is Windows Azure Web Sites and not Cloud Services (Web/Worker Role)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to setup a Cron Job to do a ping, check out Task ['Scheduling with Windows Azure Web Sites using a Cron Job Service'](http://blog.ntotten.com/2012/08/05/task-scheduling-with-windows-azure-web-sites-using-a-cron-job-service/) for an example

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a full Cloud Service (a.k.a. Web Role) you can use a startup task to set the app pools to never shut down. This script does that, as well as a few other IIS configuration changes that I found useful.

```
@ECHO OFF

@REM A file to flag that this script has already run
@REM because if we run it twice, it errors out and prevents the Azure role from starting properly
@REM %~n0 expands to the name of the currently executing file, without the extension
SET FLAGFILE=c:\%~n0-flag.txt

IF EXIST "%FLAGFILE%" (
  ECHO %FLAGFILE% exists, exiting startup script
  exit /B
) ELSE (
  date /t > %FLAGFILE%
)

@REM Enable IIS compression for application/json MIME type
@REM This will fail the second time you run it on a machine (eg, your desktop). So don't do that. 
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost

@REM Set IIS to automatically start AppPools
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.startMode:AlwaysRunning /commit:apphost

@REM Set IIS to not shut down idle AppPools
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00 /commit:apphost

@REM remove IIS response headers
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:httpProtocol /-customHeaders.[name='X-Powered-By']
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one. I also added these steps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx

Comment: I got this error: Role instances recycled for a certain amount of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent role instances from running. The most likely reason for this is that your code throws an unhandled exception. Please consider fixing your service or changing your configuration settings so that role instances do not throw unhandled exceptions. Then start another update or upgrade operation.

Comment: Here is my code: <WebRole name="MenuFinderApp.Web" vmsize="Small">
    <!--<Startup>
      <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="limited" taskType="simple">
      </Task>
    </Startup>-->

Comment: I think you probably need executionContext="elevated". Also make that the .cmd file is copied into the package - in the Visual Studio file properties it should be set to Build Action: "None" and Copy to Output Directory: "Always"